# How can I create array database row then find if value exist in array?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to search for a given value in a array from a DB row -

```
$path = '1.jpg';

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE myname='$myuser'");
$mypath = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $mypath[]= $row['path'];
}


if(array_search($path, $mypath)) {
    echo 'image exist';
}else{
    echo 'image not found in array';
}
```

But this wont work, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Wrong - `$mypath= $row['path'];` Right - `$mypath[] = $row['path'];`

Comment: sorry ya this isnt my actual script its just for example purposes..

Comment: ^ this. And "does not work" is NOT a valid problem. WHAT does not work and WHAT is the error you get?

Comment: _this isnt my actual script its just for example purposes_ And of course you decided to amend the real code from PDO or MYSQLI _Just for example purposes_

Comment: I just free handed it and wasnt thinking

Comment: It shows no output as if path doesnt exist which I know it does

Comment: So add a `print_r($mypath);` after the while loop and show us that

Comment: it prints array() to the screen

Comment: So the array is empty. If you really fixed the `$mypath = ` to `$mypath[] =` then the query is returning no rows. And its anybodies guess whats really going on in that part of the code

Comment: hmm ok thanks I will do some testing real quick

Comment: Stick this at the top of your script after the `<?php` line, if you really are using `MYSQLI` in your script `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: ok ya I got it, there was an error in my statement.. Thanks! post as an answer and Ill accept it = Wrong - $mypath= $row['path']; Right - $mypath[] = $row['path'];

Answer (score 0):

Why do you build up an array and use array search when a better SQL statement could probably do the job faster?

If you change the query to this, it will only select the rows where name **and** path match:

```
$path = '1.jpg';

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE myname='$myuser' AND path='$path'");
if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo 'image exist';
}else{
    echo 'image not found';
}
```

This should do the same job without the array overhead.

**However,** note that the code is prone to SQL injections as it is now, if the path or the name are user-provided and go into the query unchecked. Therefore you should escape these values with [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) before using them in the query.

Comment: Thanks, ya but I have multiple statements that are pulling from this match so that wouldnt work.. this was just an example to learn how to search through an array